# Filtering results in real time with AngularJS and MomentJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

I have an ng-repeat listing results but I'm aiming to only display elements containing today's date.

My current setup can do it, but needs a page reload to redefine the time variable and thus filter the results.

To be honest I'm not sure that such real-time filter (when is 00.00 the list becomes empty automatically) can be accomplished, so I'd be very grateful if you could shed some light into the issue.

Here's my current layout:

```
   <div class="row msf-row" 
     ng-repeat="record in recordlist | filter: search | filter: record.date = dateJson " 
     ng-class="{ 'msf-cancelled': record.cancelled}">
      <div class="col-md-1">{{record.date}}</div>
      <div class="col-md-1"><strong>{{record.car}}</strong></div>
      <div class="col-md-2">{{record.driver}}</div>
      <div class="col-md-2">{{record.from}}</div> 
   </div>
```

And the relevant JS:

```
 $scope.dateJson = moment().format("YYYY MM DD");
 $scope.addRecord = function () {
    $scope.recordlist.push(
            {
                date: $scope.dateJson, 
                car: $scope.carList.code, 
                driver: $scope.driverList.name,
                from: $scope.locationList.place,
                destination: $scope.locationList2.place, 
                pax: $scope.paxList
            }
        );
   jsonToRecordLocalStorage($scope.recordlist);
};
```

So basically, the filter compares the $scope.dateJson with the object property record.date and filters the results, but of course date.Json is only loaded on page reload, not on real time.

Any inputs?

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own filter function like here http://davidjs.com/2014/02/how-to-call-any-function-as-a-filter-in-angularjs/

this filter function would look something like this

```
    $scope.filterRecordsByDate = function(record) {
     var date = moment(); 
     //reset to midnight
     date.set('hours', 0).set('minutes', 0).set('seconds', 0);

     //you might need to reset to midnight also the property 'record.date'
     return record.date == date;
    }
```

Then in your HTML

```
ng-repeat="record in recordlist | filter: search | filter: filterRecordsByDate "
```